# md5 Encryption and decryption

Tags: encryption, md5

I heard that after encrypting something using the MD5 algorithm, it is not possible to decrypt the data. But for any encryption, there should be a way to decrypt the data, right?  Otherwise, what is the need of the words Encryption and Decryption?

Am I wrong?

Comment: MD5 isn't encryption, it's hashing, which isn't reversible.

Comment: md5 is a hash. hash = meat grinder. cow goes in, hamburger comes out. You cannot take that hamburger and recreate the original cow. encryption = locker. data goes in, gets locked. stick key in again, data comes out.

Comment: Oops! I didn't expected a down vote for this question. I just asked for some opinions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Basically, MD5 is not an encryption method. 

It's a [`Hash function`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hash_function), where you will lose the data due to the data processing under the function. So you wont get the old data back. So the whole point of a hash is that it's one way only. MD5 is http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cryptographic_hash_function">`cryptographic hash function` so the following things are applicable.

Some people save the user passwords using the MD5 Hash. So, even their webservers won't be knowing what exactly is your password. They only have a token for the password. Thats why in many of the websites when you request a forgot-password request, they asks you to change the password by providing a unique link instead of retrieving your old password. (Basically, they don't have your password in human readable format)

So another doubt that you could have is what if someone knows your hashed password token? The answer is simple, still you are safe, because the login authentication check converts the user input to a hash function and then checks with the DB. In this case, a new Hash value will be obtained for your hashed value.

Comment: "So the whole point of a hash is that it's one way only." - true only for cryptographic hash functions. There are a lot of algorithms that are cheaper to compute but leaks data.

Comment: @PauloScardine  Yup, you are right, forgot to mention that.

Answer (score 0):

MD5 is a hash function.

> A hash function is any function that can be used to map digital data of arbitrary size to digital data of fixed size, with slight differences in input data producing very big differences in output data (source: [wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hash_function)).

This way, the original data is not preserved. So why would you use a Hash function? It is useful for comparing arbitrary size datasets: since hashes can be short and have a fixed size, once computed any comparison is very cheap and predictable - O(1) - no matter how large the original data.

MD5 is also a cryptographic hash function. A cryptographic hash function allows one to easily verify that some input data matches a stored hash value, but makes it hard to reconstruct the data from the hash alone.

So the whole point of MD5 is that given a hash, getting back the original data should be as hard as possible.

Answer (score 0):

Here is some good reading:

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MD5

Long speech short:
MD5 basically map any string of any size to a 64bit hexadecimal number.
A *lot* of information is lost in the process and there is no way to make this information pop back.